# Script: Recursively convert wma files to MP3, then remove WMA files

Tags: bash, scripts, mp3, convert, wma

I'm trying to fix a script that recursively searches a directory tree for WMA files - converting them to MP3 files, and then removing the WMA files, leaving the converted MP3 files in their place. With some help and research this is where I'm at:

```bsh
   #!/bin/bash


shopt -s globstar


for f in **/*.[Ww][Mm][Aa]
do
    path=${f%/*}
    filename=${f##*/}
    new=${filename// /_}  # space -> underscore
    new=${new,,}             # lowercase
    mv -v -- "$f" "$path/$new"
done


for f in **/*.wma
do
    mplayer -vo null -vc dummy -af resample=44100 -ao pcm:waveheader "$f" && lame -m j -h --vbr-new -b 320 audiodump.wav -o "`basename "$f" .wma`.mp3"
    rm -f audiodump.wav
    rm -f "$f" "${f/%.wma}"
done
```

This script seems to only work on 14.04 (not on 15.10). At this point it is able to traverse sub directories, convert wma files to MP3 and delete the respective WMA files. The issue is that the MP3 files are created in the MAIN directory and not in the directories of the respective WMA files.

Comment: If you're using `basename`, the directory components will be lost. It would be created in which ever directory the command ran in.

Comment: According to the script shouldn't the script be running in each recursive directory?

Comment: Since you haven't used `cd` anywhere, nope.

Comment: The script is able to convert and delete files in directories it hasn't cd'd into. Is there some line of code I can use to move the newly created files into the directories of the files that were used to make the converted files?

Comment: Well, elsewhere you're using `"$f"` without `basename`, so that path to the file is given. It's only in the `lame` command that you're using `basename`. If you just want to strip off a `.wma` suffix, use `"${f%.wma}.mp3"`. That should retain the path.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you soo much!!!
Thank you also to Vaphell from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2306163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elsewhere you're using `"$f"` without `basename`, so that path to the file is given. It's only in the `lame` command that you're using `basename`. With `basename`, the directory components will be lost. The output file would be created in which ever directory the command ran in.

If you just want to replace a `.wma` extension with `.mp3`, use `"${f%.wma}.mp3"`. That should retain the path.