# Convert mp4 to mp3 Using Shell Script

Tags: command-line, bash, video, ffmpeg, mp3

I have looked at [Converting mp4 to mp3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84584/converting-mp4-to-mp3) which uses a tool called `ffmpeg`. The process is great when you have a single file to convert, but I'm trying automate the mp4 to mp3 conversion for any given directory.

As an example, the directory below with all its sub directories is given, i.e. MusicVideos`:

```
.
├── Andra
│   └── Andra::Why.mp4
├── Ariana Grande
│   └── Dangerous Woman
│       ├── ArianaGrande::IntoYou.mp4
│       └── ArianaGrande::SideToSide.mp4
├── Justin Bieber
│   └── JustinBieber::LetMeLoveYou.mp4
├── Major Lazer
│   └── De Maxx 37
│       └── MajorLazer::ColdWater.mp4
├── Martin Garrix & Bebe Rexha
│   └── MartinGarrix&BebeRevha::InTheNameOfLove.mp4
├── Shawn Mendes
│   └── ShawnMendes::TreatYouBetter.mp4
├── Sia
│   └── The Greatest
│       └── Sia::TheGreatest.mp4
├── The Chainsmokers
│   ├── TheChainsmokers::AllWeKnow.mp4
│   └── TheChainsmokers::Closer.mp4
├── The Weekend
│   └── Starboy
│       └── TheWeekend::DaftPunk.mp4
└── TWENTY ØNE PILØTS
    └── Suicide Squad
        └── TwentyOnePilots::Heathens.mp4
```

After the script is ran the output directory should look like, i.e., `MusicAudio`:

```
.
├── Andra
│   └── Andra::Why.mp3
├── Ariana Grande
│   └── Dangerous Woman
│       ├── ArianaGrande::IntoYou.mp3
│       └── ArianaGrande::SideToSide.mp3
├── Justin Bieber
│   └── JustinBieber::LetMeLoveYou.mp3
├── Major Lazer
│   └── De Maxx 37
│       └── MajorLazer::ColdWater.mp3
├── Martin Garrix & Bebe Rexha
│   └── MartinGarrix&BebeRevha::InTheNameOfLove.mp3
├── Shawn Mendes
│   └── ShawnMendes::TreatYouBetter.mp3
├── Sia
│   └── The Greatest
│       └── Sia::TheGreatest.mp3
├── The Chainsmokers
│   ├── TheChainsmokers::AllWeKnow.mp3
│   └── TheChainsmokers::Closer.mp3
├── The Weekend
│   └── Starboy
│       └── TheWeekend::DaftPunk.mp3
└── TWENTY ØNE PILØTS
    └── Suicide Squad
        └── TwentyOnePilots::Heathens.mp3
```

I was looking at how to do this conversion using bash scripts and i came across [Script: Recursively convert wma files to MP3, then remove WMA files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/710378/script-recursively-convert-wma-files-to-mp3-then-remove-wma-files).

This seems a bit harder than what I was anticipating for, any help and guidance will be greatly appreciated.

#### Update

With some help I've written a script:
Please confirm that this works!

```
cp -a /$1/. /$2/  #copy the whole dir from src to dest

#cd $2 #change dir to dest
cd $2
#convert *.mp4 to *.mp3
#find . -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'var=${1%.mp4}; var=${var#*/};ffmpeg -i "${1#*/}" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -qscale:a 4 -ar 48000 "$dest/$var".mp3' - '{}' \;

find . -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -qscale:a 4 -ar 48000 "${1%.mp4}".mp3' - '{}' \;

echo "Cleaning up" 
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'var=${1%.mp4}; var=${var#*/}; rm "${1#*/}"' - '{}' \;
```

You can find the source code on my [GitHub](https://github.com/Prince-of-Persia/mp4tomp3). Any further contribution will be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you will need to replicate the directory structure in the new top directory. Inside the original top directory which contains the .mp4 files run `find . -type d >dirs.txt`. This will store all directories and their paths in `dirs.txt`. Then change directory into the new top directory and run `xargs mkdir -p <dirs.txt`. This will create the same directory structure as orginal.

To change the format and store the files to a different directory run the following command inside the original top directory.

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'var=${1%.mp4}; var=${var#*/};ffmpeg -i "${1#*/}" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -qscale:a 4 -ar 48000 "~/PATH/to/NewTopDIr/$var".mp3' - '{}' \;
```

### Explanation

`find . -name "*.mp4"` finds all files of .mp4 type. `-exec bash -c` runs the bash command provided in the succeeding string for each file found. It also passes the filename as variable `$1` which can be used in the bash command.

At this point `$1` contains something like `./path/file.mp4`. To remove the filetype `*.mp4` we use `var=${1%.mp4}` which stores `./path/file` to `$var`. Now we remove the preceding `./` with `var=${var#*/}` hence the value of `$var` is `path/file`.

In the `ffmpeg` command we get the current file name with `${var#*/}` which gives path/file.mp4 and we get the output file with `~/PATH/to/NewTopDIr/$var".mp3` where `$var` has the value `path/file` as explained above.

Comment: To see what this command actually prints just add an echo before ffmpeg `find . -name "*.mp4" -exec bash -c 'echo ffmpeg -i "$1" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -qscale:a 4 -ar 48000 "${1%.mp4}".mp3' - '{}' \;`

Comment: The code that didn't have the `echo`  did work for me. Just that the converted files are in the same directory as the original files! 
Is there a way to output to a different directory with the same file structure?

Comment: I changed the command. Try now.

Comment: Just for the record, you don't need the semicolons after setting variables; `VAR=value VAR2=value command args` is legal syntax (and only sets the variables for the command).

Comment: I have tried to follow your explanation, So I made a destination folder and replaced the `"~/PATH/to/NewTopDIr/$var"` with the actual directory path. Only to find that it's not possible to do so. Then, I tried to replicate the file structure at destination with no mp4 files, and that failed too! 
sample of error message `~/Videos/MusicAudio/Major Lazer/De Maxx 37/MajorLazer::ColdWater.mp3: No such file or directory`

Comment: If `/home/amir/music-mp3` is your new directory then replace it before the `$var` variable. i.e. `"/home/amir/music-mp3/$var"`. `$var` will contain the rest of the file path i.e. `Andra/Andra::Why.mp3`.

Comment: I think the file names or directory names with spaces is causing that problem. See [how to rename directories and filenames to replace spaces with underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709458/bash-script-to-replace-spaces-in-file-names).

Comment: Oh I get it now. The command does not create the new directories. Let me add a command for that.

Comment: Replicate the directory structure using the commands `find . -type d >dirs.txt` then inside new directory `xargs mkdir -p <dirs.txt`

Comment: what `>dirs.txt` and `<dirs.txt` do?

Comment: `>dirs.txt` stores the output of the command on the left into a file named `dirs.txt`. `<dirs.txt` gives the contents to the command on the left. In this case its `xrgs` which specifically takes in arguments and performs some actions on them.

Comment: I see, as you mentioned before. The file names with space will cause problems.

Comment: Updated question body, please take a look!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46936/discussion-between-bilal-baqar-and-amir).